# I want to pass UIView isHidden property from another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I have a UIView set to hidden on a View Controller (product menu), then the user clicks on a product via tableview cell. When they hit return to the initial View Controller I want to make the UIView in the first VC visible.

When I use the code below I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

```
{
//First View Controller
@IBOutlet weak var basketView: UIView!
.
.
self.basketView?.isHidden = true
```

---

```
//Second View Controller

@IBAction func returnBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

  let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let menuCV = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController

  menuCV.basketView.isHidden = false

  self.present(menuCV, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access any outlet before the vc is presented/loaded as i'll be nil so

**Option 1**

```
menuCV.loadViewIfNeeded()
menuCV.basketView.isHidden = false
```

**Option 2**

Add a bool value

```
menuCV.hideBasket = false
```

Then set this inside `viewDidLoad` of `MenuViewController`

```
self.basketView.isHidden = hideBasket
```